# Run a batch File from my DVD

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a batch file I made to see if your running a 64bit or 32bit system. It work's great on my PC but when I put it on the DVD and ran it, it doesn't work. How do I get it to run correctly from a DVD? Thanks

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "%programfiles(x86)%" (GOTO 64-Bit) ELSE (GOTO 32-Bit)

:32-Bit
ECHO.   32-Bit Operating System Detected
GOTO END

:64-Bit
ECHO.   64-Bit Operating System Detected
GOTO END

:END

echo Press any key to exit...
pause >nul
```

SECOND TRY>>>>> Will this work?

```
@echo.off

for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%a:\programfiles(x86) set SysType=%%a:

IF EXIST "%systemroot%\programfiles(x86)" %SysType%\ (GOTO 64-Bit) ELSE (GOTO 32-Bit)
:32-Bit
ECHO. 32-Bit O/S detected
GOTO END
:64-Bit
ECHO. 64-Bit O/S detected
GOTO END
:END
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Press any key to exit...
pause >nul
```

Comment: How does it not work? Please provide details if you want someone to help you.

Comment: The error I get is the first image and it is the .bat file in my initial post. The second image is what it looks like ran from my PC. Hope this helps! 

If I just click on it on the DVD it gives me the error image.

This is what the error looks like. [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://i54.photobucket.com/albums/g94/oxicottin/Error_zpse968a275.jpg

Comment: Will something like the edits in my post work to find the directy of the program files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

IF EXIST "C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRVSTORE\GEARAspiWD_1E13C24EB2F28CB6915317F7F17F180ECAA0DB1E\x86" goto :64-Bit
if not exist "C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRVSTORE\GEARAspiWD_1E13C24EB2F28CB6915317F7F17F180ECAA0DB1E\x86" goto :32-Bit

color c
cls
echo.
echo.
echo                                  UNSPECIFIED OPERATING SYSTEM TYPE.
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause >nul
exit

:32-Bit
ECHO.   32-Bit Operating System Detected
echo.
echo.
pause >nul
goto :END

:64-Bit
ECHO.   64-Bit Operating System Detected.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause >nul
goto :END

:END
exit
```

tested and works fine for me hope it does the same for you!